# MySql: delete content from table before last month

Tags: mysql

I'm using Mysql 5.5.  I want to delete content from a table on MySql. I **only** want  to delete content that are before last month.  It means we are on " Wed Aug  6 04:37:48 EDT 2014 " and I want to delete all content except last month.

What is the query that will do this for me?  I used this query:

```
delete from TABLE_NAME
where TIMESTAMP_COLUMN < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day))
```

and the result was:

> Query OK, 31869117 rows affected (41 min 24.96 sec)

But in Phpmyadmin, I see the volume of table stile 5 Gig!

Comment: Come on, you can do better than this.

Comment: you pretty much know what you want to do, you can translate what you wrote out into sql?

Comment: Deleting data doesn't reduce the file size of your tables. But I hope you have a backup. You've deleted probably more than you wanted (as by your question).

Answer (score -1):

The following will delete all records from `your_table` where the insertdate is more than one month in the past.

```
delete from your_table where insertdate < date_sub(now(),interval 1 month)
```

Substitute table and column names as appropriate.